"The teacher came to class and advised the students." Is this sentence simple or compound. Argument for simple is it contains singular subject
If it's not simple then how it's compound, as it contains a singular subject, as compound should have compound subjects and compound predicates joined by coordinating conjunction.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is the actual problem?  If I told you that it was compound, would you understand it differently from if I told you it was simple?


The teacher [[came to class] and [advised the students]].

is a simple sentence with compound predicate.

A compound predicate occurs in a sentence when multiple verbs apply to the same subject.

For information,


A compound sentence is made up of two main clauses connected by a coordinating conjunction.


For example,
[The teacher came to class], and [he advised the students].


A compound subject is a subject with more than one noun or pronoun as the subject of a sentence.


For example,
[The teacher and his assistant] came to class.

It's also possible to say, "[The teacher] and [his assistant] // [came to class] and [advised the students]," which is a simple sentence with both a compound subject and a compound predicate.

@Misha Lavrov, yes, it's possible.

So, when subject eclipses occur, we would say that the sentence is simple with compound predicate. Thank you for your comment.

It is ellipses.  Yes.
